# .htaccess remove php extension with pretty url of multiple parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have modified my .htaccess file right now to remove the .php extension to my website. I also have a rule to have a pretty url. My problem however is I'm not sure how to add a second parameter. In addition I wanted to know if it was a problem for the rules if these parameter aren't set.

For example as of now my rules will change mywebsite.com/index.php to mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com/login.php to mywebsite.com/login and mywebsite.com/index.php?week=1 to mywebsite.com/1.

However I have now added a new parameter and my url will now be mywebsite.com/index.php?page=a?week=1 and I would like it to be change to mywebsite.com/a/1 However the "week" or the "page" parameter arent always going to be set. So it could sometimes just be index.php?week=1 or index.php?page=a or they could both be set.

Here are my current rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?week=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?week=$1
```

Is what Im asking for even possible?

Comment: You have no choice but to adapt your url scheme to distinguish both cases (except when `page` is letters only and `week` is digits only, since you can distinguish them in the matching)

Comment: The page is letters only and week numbers only

Answer (score 2):

***You can also try this***

```
RewriteEngine on
```

For week :

```
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)$ index.php?week=$1 [NC,L]
```

For page:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

For both week and page:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)/(\w+)$ index.php?week=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: When I try going to mysite.com/40 instead of taking me to week=40 I get an error 404 Object not found.

Comment: uh might have not changed the link in your view pages..just check it

Answer (score 1):

From your answer to my question (see `comments`), `page` is letters only while `week` is digits only, which makes them distinguishable. As a consequence, you do *not* have to modify your URL scheme by adding an upper-level to distinguish both cases.

That said, a working solution for your problem would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# /digit/ for "week" only
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?week=$1 [L]

# /alpha/ for "page" only
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# mix of both, order is /page/week/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&week=$2 [NC,L]
```